# Given n+1 data pairs $(x_0,y_0)...(x_n,y_n)$ for j=0,1,2...,n we have $p_j=\prod_{i\neq j}(x_j-x_i)$ and $\psi(x)=\prod_{i=0}^n(x-x_i)$.

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

Given n+1 data pairs $(x_0,y_0)...(x_n,y_n)$ for j=0,1,2...,n we have 
$p_j=\prod_{i\neq j}(x_j-x_i)$ and $\psi(x)=\prod_{i=0}^n(x-x_i)$.

I am having trouble determining what $\psi(x_j)$ is and what $\psi'(x_j)$ would be.

I feel like $\psi(x_j)= 0$ because it would contain the $x_j-x_j$ term... But I feel like I am missing something...

Comment: Where are the $y_k$ used, and what is the actual question?

Comment: The question is to show that $p_j=\psi'(x_j)$ for part a. The second part uses the $y_i$ but I am just wondering about the first part right now...

Comment: I am mostly just trying to understand the notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't missing something; $\psi(x_j)=0$ and the reason is the one you wrote. As for finding $\psi'(x_j)$ one way is to "differenciate logarithmically";
$$
\log\psi(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n\log(x-x_i);
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left[\log\psi(x)\right]=\sum_i\frac{d}{dx}\log(x-x_i)=\sum_i\frac{1}{x-x_i}.
$$
Now, in the other hand we know that $\frac{d}{dx}\log\psi(x)=\frac{\psi'(x)}{\psi(x)}$, so
$$
\psi'(x)=\psi(x)\sum_i\frac{1}{x-x_i}=\sum_ip_i(x).
$$
Now plug in $x=x_j$.

Comment: How do we get two answers for the derivative?

Comment: They are not different. It is just expressed in two ways, like $12=2\cdot6=4\cdot3$.

Comment: Oh thank you. I see it now. Then $\psi'(x_j)$ would be zero wouldn't it...

Comment: No. $\psi'(x_j)=p_j(x_j)$. Ok I see where you are confused; as my answer is worded I am defining $p_k(x)=\prod_{i\neq k}(x-x_i)$, so $p_j(x_j)$ would be what you called $p_j$ in the first place. Sorry for thee confussion. Nevertheless, $\psi'(x_j)=p_j(x_j)$ (not zero, assuming all the $x_0,...,x_n$ are different) because $p_i(x_j)=0$ iff $i\neq j$. It is just as the answer says, just plug $x=x_j$ in the last equation.

Comment: Thank you for helping me... and for your patience. I think I am starting to get a handle on this. The key I think I was missing is to simplify $\psi'(x)$ into an expanded polynomial form before plugging in $x_j$ or else I get the wrong solution.

Comment: Don't worry, we are all here to learn. Or at least this is how I see it. For the future just try to make the question clear as possible. =)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\psi'(x) = \sum_{j=0}^n \left(\prod_{i \ne j} (x-x_i)\right)$ by the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule).

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate the help.