# derivative of $\psi(x)=\prod_{i=0}^n(x-x_i)$.

Tags: derivatives

Find the derivative of
$\psi(x)=\prod_{i=0}^n(x-x_i)$.

$$
\log\psi(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n\log(x-x_i);
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left[\log\psi(x)\right]=\sum_i\frac{d}{dx}\log(x-x_i)=\sum_i\frac{1}{x-x_i}.
$$
Now, in the other hand we know that $\frac{d}{dx}\log\psi(x)=\frac{\psi'(x)}{\psi(x)}$, so
$$
\psi'(x)=\psi(x)\sum_i\frac{1}{x-x_i}$$

I am not sure why I am getting two different derivatives... Or are they the same and I am missing something...Thanks.

Comment: What are the two derivatives? I only see one.

Comment: @ryBear You first posted this as a comment under the accepted answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2002612/291201). Please wait for followups to that comment before posting a brand new question. There are no *two* derivatives, anyway.

Comment: @dxiv sorry about that. I felt that it was a different question...

Comment: @mfl I thought that the two were $\sum_i\frac{1}{x-x_i}$ and $\psi(x)\sum_i\frac{1}{x-x_i}$? Are these the same and I am just not seeing it?

Comment: @ryBear Those two derivatives are not of the *same* function. One is $(\log \psi(x))'$, the other $(\psi(x))'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take note of the fact that if you have differentiable functions $f_1, f_2, \cdots f_n$ that if we put $f = \prod_{k=1}^n f_k$ then
$$f' = \sum_{k=1}^n f_k' \left(\prod_{j\not=k}f_j\right)$$
No logs are needed; this is a straoghtforward generalization of the familiar product rule of Calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Your derivation is correct. If you differentiate directly with the product rule:

$(f_1f_2...f_n)'=f_1'f_2...f_n+f_1f_2'...f_n+...f_1f_2...f_n'$

you will get the same result.